# Obtain data from pandas dataframe based on the column containing column names provided at each record

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a 'data' dataframe that contain col_names that have various column names within that dataframe.  I need a new column corresponding to col_names for each row.  In the following example, the new column (say D) should have 2 and 30 for first and second records respectively

```
import pandas as pd 

# Initialise data to lists. 
data = [{'col_names': 'b', 'b': 2, 'c':3}, {'col_names':'c', 'b': 20, 'c': 30}] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

Comment: Use `df.lookup()`.

Comment: What values will go in that column?

Comment: @Daniel Butler - df.lookup() actually answers my question.  In the new column, the values corresponding the column name in the 'col_names' should be present for each row.